# linear combination of vectors with determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

If $(x,y,z)$ not equal to and $(\vec{\imath}+\vec{\jmath}+\vec k)x+(3\vec{\imath}-3\vec j+\vec k)y+(-4\vec{\imath}+5\vec{\jmath}+\vec{k})=a(x\vec i+y\vec j+z\vec k)$ then $a=?$ (where $ i,k,j$ are unit vectors)

Comment: "not equal to" what?

Comment: not equal to zero i m sorry

Comment: Please edit that into the body, Kimmy, instead of leaving it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

$(\vec{\imath}+\vec{\jmath}+\vec k)x+(3\vec{\imath}-3\vec j+\vec k)y+(-4\vec{\imath}+5\vec{\jmath}+\vec{k})=(x+3y-4)\vec{\imath}+(x-3y+5)\vec{\jmath}+(x+y-4)\vec k=a(x\vec i+y\vec j+z\vec k)$ so
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x+3y-4=ax \\\\
x-3y+5= ay\\\\
 x+y-4=az
\end{matrix}\right.
 $$ so
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
(1-a)x+3y=4 \\\\
x+(-3-a)y=-5\\\\
 x+y-az=4
\end{matrix}\right.$$ $ (1-a)(-3-a)-3$ has no root hence you can calculate $x,y$
then $z$

$$x = \frac { \begin{vmatrix} {\color{red}4} & 3 & 0 \\ {\color{red}{-5}} & -3-a &0 \\ {\color{red}4} & 1 & -a \end{vmatrix} } { \begin{vmatrix} 1-a & 3 & 0 \\ 1 & -3-a & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & -a\end{vmatrix} },....$$

Comment: thx i want it with determinants

Comment: I added $x$, continue this way.